# How to get live reactions

Tags: discord, discord.py

I would like to know how I would be able to get live reactions to the emoji being clicked. Right now the code checks the 10 users after the 60 seconds has been over and then returns a number of how many users have reacted to the emoji.

```
            message_id = await ready_channel.fetch_message(sent_message.id)
            ready_players = 0 
            for reacted in message_id.reactions:
                ready_players += reacted.count -1
                print(ready_players)
                if ready_players == 10:
                    veto_embed = discord.Embed(description='READIED', color=discord.Color.red())
                    await ready_channel.send(embed=veto_embed)
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the [reaction event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add)?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for

I saw that this could be my possible answer. But i am unsure how i would count the users/members on reaction to the emoji.

Comment: You can grab the [reactions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.reactions) on the `Message` object and then pull the [count](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Reaction.count) for each reaction.